# Jade ClientSide Template Inheritance

Tags: pug

Jade inheritance in clientside give me this error:

```
Error: failed to require "path"
```

Any solution?

or is it possible to use inheritance on client side?

Comment: You need to add details. How do you import the files, scripts etc...

Answer (score 0):

you are using path somewhere in your code, like this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

So you should add the path module like this :

```
var express = require('express')
  , path = require('path');
```